# How to find out whether a message contain keywords from a column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am new in MySQL. i have a table block_keywords with two columns id and keywords. I want to find out whether a message contain block keyword or not. I try to use LIKE but in this scenario LIKE didn't work. Then i try  `FIND_IN_SET`

ex.

```
 SELECT * FROM block_keywords WHERE FIND_IN_SET(keywords,'testing...keyword*231*717#')>0;
```

In table, keyword *231*717# exist. But it return nothing.

I want to know is there any way to achieve this?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CONCAT` you can search for words:

```
SELECT * FROM block_keywords WHERE 'testing keyword 231' LIKE CONCAT('%', keywords, '%');
```

Where "keywords" is the column name and the keywords itself are a space-separated glued string.

Comment: if i achieve the same through loop in java(means iterate the whole list of keywords and compare with message). Can you suggest which way is the faster way ?

Comment: Database is definately faster than iterating all results in Java. Definately.

Answer (score 0):

Use concat along with Like

```
SELECT * FROM block_keywords WHERE CONCAT(id,keywords) LIKE "Yourkeyword%"
```